# how to make sure that posix_time_zone constructor won't crash when invalid string is passed as argument

Tags: c++, boost, posix

I am trying to use posix_time_zone as below in our project.

```
time_zone_ptr zone(new posix_time_zone(localTimeZone.c_str()));
const string hasDST = zone->has_dst() ? "true" : "false";
const int Year = second_clock::local_time().date().year();
const string stTime = to_iso_extended_string(zone->dst_local_start_time(Year));
const string endTime = to_iso_extended_string(zone->dst_local_end_time(Year));
```

localTimeZone will be set by another application in the project. I need to use that value to get dst related parameters through posix_time_zone. I don't have control on what value another application is setting and I am getting the following crash.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb5a7f8a6 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0xb5a8dcde in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xb5a905b6 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0xb5c3e1e6 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at ../../../../gcc-linaro-4.8-2014.11/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#4  0xb5c3ce60 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>) at ../../../../gcc-linaro-4.8-2014.11/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:38
#5  0xb5c3ce7c in std::terminate () at ../../../../gcc-linaro-4.8-2014.11/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:48
#6  0xb5c3d068 in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0xb4f00a90, tinfo=0xb60a7e34 <typeinfo for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >>,
dest=0xb60665e1 <boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >::~clone_impl()>) at ../../../../gcc-linaro-4.8-2014.11/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:87
#7  0xb6062dc0 in void boost::throw_exception<boost::bad_lexical_cast>(boost::bad_lexical_cast const&) () from /usr/local/lib/libmbtime.so
#8  0xb60631aa in boost::detail::lexical_cast_do_cast<int, std::string>::lexical_cast_impl(std::string const&) () from /usr/local/lib/libmbtime.so
#9  0xb605f3ea in int boost::lexical_cast<int, std::string>(std::string const&) () from /usr/local/lib/libmbtime.so
#10 0xb605b686 in boost::posix_time::time_duration boost::date_time::str_from_delimited_time_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, char>(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
```

from /usr/local/lib/libmbtime.so
    #11 0xb605c80e in boost::local_time::posix_time_zone_base::calc_zone(std::string const&) () from /usr/local/lib/libmbtime.so
    #12 0xb6059440 in boost::local_time::posix_time_zone_base::posix_time_zone_base(std::string const&) () from /usr/local/lib/libmbtime.so
    #13 0xb6054e1e in PlatformTime::TimeZoneHandler(void*) () from /usr/local/lib/libmbtime.so
    #14 0xb6f7d170 in ?? () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
    (gdb) quit

This might be because localTimeZone is having some invalid value (one more issue is I am using c string which I need to change C++ string). Can any one please give any suggestion how to test whether the localTimeZone is having correct format boost is expecting.

Comment: catch the `bad_lexical_cast` around the constructor for `time_zone_ptr` and post the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor of `boost::local_time::posix_time_zone` throws `std::invalid_argument`, `std::out_of_range` or `boost::bad_lexical_cast` (the one in this case) if the passed value is invalid. Catch these exceptions (or catch their common parent `std::exception`) and it won't crash.

Comment: Thanks StenSoft for listing all the exceptions it will throw.

Comment: Gotta Catch'em All!! `catch(std::exception const& e)`